# How do I increase the maximum amount of players in a server or host?

Tags: borderlands-2

I want to host massive raid servers for Borderlands 2, like 30 or so players. I have tried searching it but all I find is LEVEL CAP or 4 player co-op. D:

I want to farm for Vermivorous the Invincible with high spawn rates.

Comment: How do you know 30-player spawn rates will be high, if the game has spawn rates only for 4 players?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but the maximum number of players you can have in a room is 4. This isn't a super-customizable game like Counter-Strike.

Answer (score -1):

actually there is configuration settings to change the player limit but i'm not sure you can have 5 or more players in one session. However, if you are willing to test it then go to:

Users > (UserName) > Documents > MyGames > Borderlands > WillowGame > Config > WillowGami.ini

you'll see:

```
[Engine.GameInfo]
DefaultGlobals=WillowGame.WillowGlobals
DefaultGame=WillowGame.WillowCoopGameInfo
DefaultServerGame=WillowGame.WillowCoopGameInfo
bAdminCanPause=false
MaxPlayers=4
```

At the top. Simply change `MaxPlayers=(desired amount)` and test it out yourself
Do note however, Borderlands is not designed for co-op with more than 4 players so the chance of it working is unlikely.